# Dos war casi identicos en el tomcat

Tags: java, excepciones, tomcat, war

Tengo dos versiones de una misma aplicación java que apuntan a distintos esquemas de una misma base de datos por mucho que modifico el pom.xml, tomcat me los identifica como iguales dandome un "javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException:"

¿Cómo gestiona tomcat los war? ¿ En que se basa para decir que son iguales?

Comment: Pues, si el contexto que van a levantar ambas aplicaciones es el mismo (`/miApp`), no te va a funcionar porque Catalina no logra crear un nuevo contexto que se llame igual a otro que ya existe.

Comment: Realmente tomcat usa el nombre del war para decidir el nombre/ruta, prueba a cambiar el nombre del WAR de una de las dos

Comment: el nombre es diferente tanto el del war como el del pom, entiendo que el contexto es diferente también